# Why isn't my data populated when i used VBA to create worksheets beforehand?

Tags: excel, vba, performance

Previously, when I created the worksheets index 1,2,3 in excel, 
[image]

it can be sorted into like this in index 1 2 and 3 respectively
[image]

But now if i stop creating worksheets in excel but through VBA instead, the data cant be populated and it leaves index 1,2 and 3 empty.
[image]

This is the code that I used for populating the data but with the addition of add.sheets. The add.sheets here are for creating index1,2,3 worksheets but they doesn't trigger the program to continue to populate the data even though these worksheets exists when I program them in VBA.

```
 Sub UpdateVal()
        Static count As Long
        Dim iRow As Long
        Dim aRow As Long
        Dim a As Long
        Dim b As Long
        Dim selectRange As Range
        Dim lastline As Integer
        Dim sheetname As String
        Dim indexrowcount As Integer
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Result")
        Set site_ai = Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Worksheets.count)) 
        site_ai.Name = "Index1"
        Set site_bi = Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Worksheets.count))
        site_bi.Name = "Index2"
        Set site_ci = Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Worksheets.count))
        site_ci.Name = "Index3"**


       '^additional codes sheets.Add added here for creating worksheets namely index1,2,3



        j = 2
        iRow = 1
        lastline = ws.UsedRange.Rows.count
        While iRow < lastline + 1
            a = iRow + 1
            b = iRow + 17 ' Max Group Size with Same name in F to H column
            count = 1
            If ws.Cells(iRow, "F").Value = "Martin1" Then
                sheetname = "Index1"
            ElseIf ws.Cells(iRow, "F").Value = "John1" Then
                sheetname = "Index2"
            Else
                sheetname = "Index3"
            End If
            For aRow = a To b
                If ws.Cells(iRow, "F") = ws.Cells(aRow, "F") And ws.Cells(iRow, "G") = ws.Cells(aRow, "G") And ws.Cells(iRow, "H") = ws.Cells(aRow, "H") Then
                    count = count + 1
                Else
                    Set selectRange = Range("A" & iRow & ":J" & aRow - 1)
                    selectRange.Copy
                    indexrowcount = Sheets(sheetname).UsedRange.Rows.count
                    Sheets(sheetname).Range("A" & indexrowcount).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                    iRow = iRow + count
                    Exit For
               End If
            Next aRow
        Wend
    End Sub
```

what am I missing here and how should i solve it?

Comment: Why do you have three columns with the same data? Also, `site_ci.Name = "Index3"**` if giving a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is too confusing. If your example data is accurate, I don't understand why you need to check all three columns. You can accomplish what you are trying to do, by just using `column F`. If your data is already sorted as shown, then I would loop through `column F` testing for duplicates until no match. I would then add a worksheet and name it using the start cells' value. Then copy the rows from the start cell to the current `rwNbr - 1` and paste to the new worksheet. Reset the start cell for the next group and loop.

```
Sub SaveRangewithConsecutiveDuplicateValuestoNewSheet()
'Define all variables
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, sCel As Range, rwNbr As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'Set workbook variable
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'set worksheet variable using workbook variable

Set sCel = ws.Cells(1, 6) 'Set the first start cell variable to test for duplicate values

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        For rwNbr = 2 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, 6).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row Step 1 'Loop

            If ws.Cells(rwNbr, 6).Value <> sCel.Value Then 'loop until the value changes
                wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.count)).Name = sCel.Value 'Add sheet and name based on the first cell of group

                ws.Range(sCel, ws.Cells(rwNbr - 1, 6)).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("A1") 'select group of consecutive duplicates

                Set sCel = ws.Cells(rwNbr, 6) 'reset start cell to test for the next group of consecutive duplicates
            End If

        Next rwNbr
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: ok technically my code works as it should be without the add.sheets and it will sort the data and paste them accordingly but that is with worksheet index 1, index 2 and index 3 created in excel workbook. But now when the worksheets are not created in excel, but instead i use vba to create this worksheets through add.sheets, the data wont be sorted and paste even they exists

Comment: your code gets the idea that what I want but how to code such that you named the sheets as index 1,index2,index3 instead of naming them based on cell value like martin,charlie like the one that you used   wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.count)).Name = sCel.Value